# CSS relative slide over absolute to hover over

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to make a game where the user is unable to resize/scale the screen without it getting messed up. I'm working with 1 big background and dynamic elements on top of it. Currently the elements are not scaling (they are scaled to the browser window), wich is good, but placing them in such position was already a difficult task.

So the main goal is that if the user hovers over an image (div) then the div should move up with X pixels. But those relative images are placed in an absolute box (to perform left and top css modification to window)

Research on the net said trying negative margins, but that didn't seem to work, the margins are indeed going negative, but the div just stays where it is.

The JSFiddle for my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/uyx09byn/2/

What's the proper way to solve this, this is my current jQuery code to maintain the aspect ratio:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    setSizes();
});


$(window).resize(function() 
{
    setSizes();
});

var widthMultiplier;
var heightMultiplier;

var normalWidth = 1920;
var normalHeight = 1080;
var offsets;
function setSizes()
{
    widthMultiplier = ($(window).height()/9*16) / normalWidth;
    heightMultiplier = $(window).height() / normalHeight;

    //Background Image
    $('#stadium').height($(window).height());
    $('#stadium').width($(window).height()/9*16);

    offsets = $('#stadium').offset();

    //playerspace
    $("#players").width(946 * widthMultiplier);
    $("#players").height(130 * heightMultiplier);

    $("#players").css("left", (((1920 * widthMultiplier) * 29.8 / 100) + offsets.left) + "px");
    $("#players").css("top", (((1080 * heightMultiplier) * 77.9 / 100) + offsets.top) + "px");


    //players
    $(".player").width(86 * widthMultiplier);
    $(".player").height(115 * heightMultiplier);
    $(".player").css("margin", (5.5 * heightMultiplier) + "px " + (4 * widthMultiplier) + "px " + (4 * heightMultiplier) + "px " + (4 * widthMultiplier) + "px");

    var lefttemp;
    $(".player").mouseover(function()
    {
        console.log("UP: " + this.id);
        $(this).css({marginTop: '-=15px'});
    });
    $(".player").mouseout(function()
    {
        console.log("DOWN: " + this.id);
        $(this).css({marginTop: '+=15px'});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uyx09byn/17/

A large part of your problem is a lot of what you're trying to accomplish with Javascript is much better done using CSS.

For example these lines:

```
$('#stadium').height($(window).height());
$('#stadium').width($(window).height()/9*16);
```

Can be replaced with this CSS:

```
max-width: 1920px;
width: calc(100vh / 9 * 16);
max-height: 1080px;
height: 100vh;
```

"100vh" is 100% of the viewport height.

The scaling effect you were attempting to accomplish with Javascript is better done by setting a `padding-bottom: XX%;`on the element in question. The percentage should be set according to the element's width to achieve the intended ratio. For example, if you had 2 elements each taking up 50% of their parent, the padding-bottom set would be 50% if you intended them to be square.

As for moving up X pixels on hover, you just need this:

```
.player:hover {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-15px);
    transition: all .3s;
}
```

The `transform` moves the element the desired direction (in this case, 15 pixels up the Y axis), the transition makes the transform a bit smoother, and the `backface-visibility: hidden;`triggers hardware acceleration for the transform/transition.